# How to bypass pull requests for certain users in github?

Tags: git, github

In the github repo, 'require pull requests before merging the code is enabled'. How do I bypass this to enable code merge in the master branch without creating any pull request only for certian users ?

Is it possible ?

Comment: I don't know, but either everyone should work according to the "requre pull requests" workflow, or you don't need it at all.

Comment: Normally, administrators can push directly, no? Or is that not the case with that option enabled?

Answer (score 0):

Since Nov. 2021, this is now possible:

> ### [Allow bypassing required pull requests](https://github.blog/changelog/2021-11-19-allow-bypassing-required-pull-requests/)
>
> This is a good practice, but you may want to make exceptions to this rule for specific people and teams.
> For example, if you have an automated process that calls GitHub APIs to make changes in a repository, you may want to permit that automation to make changes without creating a pull request.
>
> Now, when you require pull requests and their related protections for a branch, you can specify people and teams who should be free from those requirements.
>
> As shown in the image below, select Allow specific actors to bypass pull request requirements. Then, search for and select the people and teams who should be allowed to bypass the requirements.
>
> [image: Screenshot of option to bypass PR requirements -- https://github.blog/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/bypass-pull-request-requirements.png?resize=715%2C375?w=715]
>
> For more information, visit Managing a branch protection rule.

Caveat:

> Protected branches are available
>
> - in public repositories with GitHub Free and GitHub Free for organizations, and
> - in public and private repositories with GitHub Pro

Comment: This feature only applies to repositories belonging to an organisation.

Comment: @GiorgosMyrianthous Indeed, thank you for the feedback. I have edited the answer accordingly.